# UIPAGEVIEWCONTROLLER Datasource methods called Twice on Fast Swipe

Tags: objective-c, datasource, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to implement the basic `UIPageviewController` Example.But when I swipe fastly in right/left direction, the datasource method `viewcontrollerAfterViewController` is getting called twice.It is happening in ios 7 only. Any body knows why this happens?

Comment: I am using the code from http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIPageViewController` uses these bellow method for getting the back and front ViewController.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

Though its weird but yes its a known issue. Every time it calls Before and After method to get VC. It there is no next VC then it returns `nil` and if there is no previous VC the `datasourceDelegate` return `nil`, otherwise it return the index of VC.

In `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`, there is a function named :

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers;
```

Look at this it might help to get the current or next/previous viewcontroller from `pendingViewControllers` array.

Hope this helps.. :)